# Value Class w/ `val` Field

Tags: scala

Reading the [Value Classes and Universal Traits](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) post, I looked at the `RichInt` example.

But, I changed the `self` field to leave off the `val`.

```
scala> class RichInt(self: Int) extends AnyVal {
     |  def toHexString: String = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(self)
     | }
<console>:7: error: value class parameter must be a val and not be private[this]
       class RichInt(self: Int) extends AnyVal {
                     ^
```

I got a compile-time error. It appears that omitting the `val` results in the field have accessibility of `private[this]`.

What's the significance of keeping versus excluding `val`? I'm not sure what `must be a val` actually means.

Comment: This topic seems to be similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944356/value-classes-introduce-unwanted-public-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the wording *must be a val* is a bit off. More specifically, the value class parameter *must be a public val*, as stated in that very article.

> A value class …
>
> … must have only a primary constructor with exactly **one public, val parameter** whose type is not a value class.

Declaring `class RichInt(val self: Int) extends AnyVal`, means that a public accessor for `self` will be created by the compiler for class `RichInt`. If you remove the `val` declaration from within the constructor, then `self` will be private within instances of the class (and only accessible to `this` instance).

Comment: It also says *(From Scala 2.11.0, the parameter may be non-public.)*, but that doesn't seem to work in 2.11.

Comment: `class RichInt(private val self: Int) extends AnyVal {}` works for me using 2.11.6

Comment: Ah, I guess it's that it just can't be `private[this]`.

Comment: @m-z, I'm confused by `then self will be private within instances of the class (and only accessible to this instance).` Instantiating a case class, `Foo(x: String)`, allows the `x` field to be "gotten" via a public accessor.

Comment: @KevinMeredith But case classes are special, they automatically add public accessors for the constructor fields, unless otherwise specified. Regular classes do not do this, they are automatically `private[this]`. The `RichInt` example is not a case class, and therefore no automatic public accessor.